# How to read and store empty data in a string

Tags: c++, string

I have a table which contains some fields empty. Now i have to read those fields and store in a string and return the string. Currently I'm reading those fields and storing in a structure and copying it to string.

```
memcpy(messagePkt.CardValidityEndDate,
  boomer::utils::str::to_hex(transaction.CardID).c_str(), 4);
```

`messagePkt` is a struct with a field `CardValidityEndDate`, while `transaction.CardID` is a field of a database.

Copying data from structure to string

```
const char* data = (const char*)&messagePkt;
transactionLog.insert(0, data, sizeof(messagePkt));
```

`transactionLog`: Final string in which I have to store

But when I am checking the string, nothing is coming.

Comment: What library are you using for this `transactionLog` and what do the `insert()` parameters mean? What does `nothing is coming` mean? What is `to_hex()` and what happens if the string returned is less than 4 bytes long?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]